# Script for collecting all translatable strings in the codebase?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have hundreds of strings in my code-base that which translation i.e. strings inside **`t()`** function.

Is there a script that can traverse through my code-base and collect all the strings and export them to an excel file?

Or else, Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

By default, every string you wrap in the t() function is going to be added to the localization database by the core [Drupal locale module](https://drupal.org/node/322729) as soon as Drupal encounters the occurrence. You can then use the translation interface to search for these new strings and update them manually or export a [Gettext Portable Object Template](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) file

http://example.com/admin/config/regional/translate/export

These files are in text format and easily editable by non-technical users, ex:

```
#: misc/tabledrag.js
msgid "Hide row weights"
msgstr ""
```

There are a number of tools available for working with gettext files, I would recommend the [Localization client module](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client) for doing this work within the Drupal interface. There is also an option to convert these files to excel and back using csv2po but I haven't used this:

http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/guides/using_csv2po.html